# Making a local site become Global

Tags: web, xampp, portforwarding, dmz

I've created a website on my personal computer, and now I want to make it global.
I know that I can host in on a hosting website (such as [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com)), but I prefer using my computer as the server.
The website is now working and OK, the question is how do I open it to the global network.
I have tried using DMZ, and i't worked, but my friend told me that It is unsafe and helps the viruses to attack me. Is there any other way to do it?

I heared something about *port forwarding*, but I didn't find how to do it on my router

---

I apologise if my English is not good enough, I speak Hebrew at home

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have any additions to your question, don't post them in comments, it is better to edit the post. The edit link is right under the tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DMZ** and it actually stands for Demilitarized Zone. The DMZ sits between the Internet and an internal network's line of defense. So by putting your computer in the DMZ you are putting it in front of your router and its firewall protection.

Generally a DMZ does NOT bypass firewall rules and does NOT allow all packets to get to it. Typical design is to have a DMZ with true public IP addresses protected by a firewall. This firewall says what can come in and what can go out, drop/reject all else. Firewall also permits special applications from an internal network but not from an external. Hence the term DMZ.

Now the above is for devices called firewalls. What you have is a NAT device and by placing a host in the "DMZ" you are saying "send all packets not associated with an existing NAT coversation to this host" effectively bypassing any security you may have.

A lot of applications like instant messengers, FTP, H.323, and SQLnet negotiate port numbers during the session setup at layers 5/7 and don't work behind NAT unless the NAT device can inspect these higher layer protocols and make the necessary adjustments. By setting your router to place this host in the "DMZ" you don't need to worry about the NAT problems because the router blindly forwards the frames to the host irregardless or any negotiated port numbers.

In networking terms what you are really doing is called a "static NAT". Forward all frames to 24.24.24.24 to 192.168.0.1. This is by definition a NAT and really isn't a DMZ.

**Port forwarding** allows you to leave your computer(s) behind the router and open up only the ports you want accessible from the internet. Your router will forward the information coming in to the computer you designated to receive the info.

1- If you have **Linksys** maybe you can find **port forwarding** in **applications and gaming** tab.

2- On **D-link** Routers you can find it in **advanced** tab

3- On **Zyxel** you can find it in **Network>Nat>Port forwarding**

4- And if you have **TP link** you can find it on **advanced setup**